# Match lookup value with importHTML and combine tables in Soogle Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have total 2 url links both of which match lookup value and want column of second table in first table.

I have first taken a table from the importhtml formula. And the cell that is green is the column lookup value. Which is as follows.

**1st table** https://www.screener.in/screens/881782/rk-all-stocks/?page=21

```
=QUERY(IMPORTHTML("https://www.screener.in/screens/881782/rk-all-stocks?page=1", "table",1),"where Col1 is not null",1)
```

[image]

And there is another table in which I want to match the lookup values from the first table and all the values from that table. Which I have tried. Within this google sheet and you can also try in this google sheet.\

```
=VLOOKUP(B3,IMPORTHTML("https://www.screener.in/screens/881791/rk-holding/?page=1", "table",1),12,0)
```

**2nd table** https://www.screener.in/screens/881791/rk-holding/?page=1

[image]

In column next to roce I want column of promoter holding. Which you have to take from this url link.

**get result like**

[image]

try this in google sheet. : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yawdkBHkheaXeziWHFBFd3gngO3EQJr0d19lUH9cVfI/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

added formula to your sheet

Cell L3:

`=BYROW(B3:B,LAMBDA(bx,IF(bx="",,IFNA(QUERY(IMPORTHTML("https://www.screener.in/screens/881791/rk-holding/?page=1", "table",1),"Select Col12, Col13 Where Col2='"&bx&"'",0)))))`

-

[image]

Comment: Thank You Sir. This is the work best.. But only search page 1 how to add Multiple pages like page 1, 2 , 3 etc..