# Match lookup value with importHTML tables in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Asked this same question before and got the answer and it works fine too. This is how I want the answer in the formula I give.

Please read : [Match lookup value with importHTML and combine tables in Soogle Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74992548/match-lookup-value-with-importhtml-and-combine-tables-in-soogle-sheet)

@[rockinfreakshow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5479575/rockinfreakshow) Thank You so much for this answer. Sir please answer me according to my formula.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I want the answer in the same way, but I match the lookup value from another url link with them in the same way as the answer comes from the formula I show and I want the answer.

1. I have this formula. And I get the answer well. Which you will get with the result in the link of google sheet below.

   1st URL : https://www.screener.in/screens/881782/rk-all-stocks/?limit=25&page=1

```
=arrayformula( 
  lambda( 
    baseUrl, pageStart, pageEnd, 
    query( 
      reduce( 
        importhtml(baseUrl & pageStart, "table"), 
        sequence(pageEnd - pageStart, 1, pageStart + 1), 
        lambda( 
          result, pageNumber, 
          { 
            result; 
            iferror( 
              importhtml(baseUrl & pageNumber, "table"), 
              iferror(sequence(1, 11) / 0) 
            ) 
          } 
        ) 
      ), 
      "where Col1 is not null", 1 
    ) 
  )( 
    "https://www.screener.in/screens/881782/rk-all-stocks/?limit=25&page=", 1, 57 
  ) 
)
```

Result Screenshot

[image]

2. And there is another table in which I want to match the lookup value of the first table and all the values of that table. Which I have tried. Within this google sheet and you can also try this google sheet.

2nd URL with match 1st URL Record : https://www.screener.in/screens/881791/rk-holding/?page=1

```
=BYROW(B2:B,LAMBDA(bx,IF(bx="",,IFNA(QUERY(IMPORTHTML("https://www.screener.in/screens/881791/rk-holding/?page=1", "table",1),"Select Col12, Col13 Where Col2='"&bx&"'",0)))))
```

If I use this formula I get only 25 data.

Result Screenshot

[image]

If I use this formula I get only 1 page of data. As this url link has more than 165 pages.

**i expected result**

I only get as much data as in the first formula. Next to them i.e next to ROCE you need column number 12 and 13 from another URL link. Lookup values match and look for the data next to them. Lookup value column number will be 2. Which I have tried in this google sheet and you can also try.

try this in google sheet : **[OPEN GOOGLE SHEET](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1acEwDjVOePGkN0prQdsFctFsA11GMgjv-pk3Hsh0-iI/edit?usp=sharing)**

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Updated the solution in your [sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1acEwDjVOePGkN0prQdsFctFsA11GMgjv-pk3Hsh0-iI/edit#gid=2086714359)

[image]

Comment: Sir withouth add `{P:AB}` Column data direct fetch from URL. sir please again try data provide in google sheet -  [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1acEwDjVOePGkN0prQdsFctFsA11GMgjv-pk3Hsh0-iI/edit?usp=sharing]

Comment: The Sheet is loading forever & crashing for direct fetch. Just replace the `{P:AB}` part with formula in Cell P1 and test it for yourself.

Comment: While links to external resources might be helpful posts on this sites should be self contained. Considering this add all the relevant details directly into the answer body. Formulas should be added as text not as images.