# How to scrape multiple table including contained href with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

All tables are obtained using `pandas`. But it only gets table data. The `href` link is lost.

Is there any solution to get side link with table data?

###### Example - 1

```
import pandas as pd

for page in range(1,10):
    df = pd.read_html('https://www.screener.in/screens/881782/rk-all-stocks/?page={page}'.format(page=page))
    df[0].to_csv('tab.csv',  mode='a', index=False, header=1)
```

###### Example - 2

```
import pandas as pd

dfs = []

url = 'https://www.screener.in/screens/881782/rk-all-stocks/?page={}'
for i in range(1,10):    
    df = pd.read_html(url.format(i), header=None)[0]      
    dfs.append(df)

finaldf = pd.concat(dfs)              
finaldf.to_csv('Output.csv')
```

###### Output

[image]

###### Expected output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if `pd.read_html` has an option to `extract_links`, sometimes it's easier to do it manually especially for this kind of request:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import bs4

url = 'https://www.screener.in/screens/881782/rk-all-stocks/?page={}'

cols = ['S.No.', 'Name', 'CMP', 'P/E', 'Mar Cap', 'Div Yld', 'NP Qtr', 'Qtr Profit Var', 'Sales Qtr', 'Qtr Sales Var', 'ROCE']

def extract_data(row):
    data = dict(zip(cols, [cell.text.strip() for cell in row.find_all('td')]))
    data.update({'href': f"https//www.screener.in/{row.find('a')['href']}"})
    return data

data = []
for page in range(1, 10):    
    r = requests.get(url.format(page))
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.content)
    rows = soup.find_all('tr', {'data-row-company-id': True})
    df = pd.DataFrame([extract_data(row) for row in rows])
    data.append(df)
data
out = pd.concat(data, ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
    S.No.              Name      CMP    P/E   Mar Cap Div Yld  NP Qtr Qtr Profit Var Sales Qtr Qtr Sales Var     ROCE                                               href
0      1.      R J Bio-Tech     6.00             5.68    0.00  -17.41          33.07      1.74       1833.33  2400.00            https//www.screener.in//company/536456/
1      2.       Forbes & Co   627.20   0.17    809.09    0.00   -4.08        -128.11    103.43        -24.35  1216.69  https//www.screener.in//company/FORBESGOK/cons...
2      3.    Nexus Surgical    10.90             5.97    0.00    0.14         -62.16      0.30        -83.05  1114.29            https//www.screener.in//company/538874/
3      4.      SBEC Systems    25.65  42.75     25.65    0.00    0.15         -46.43      0.67        -10.67  1107.32  https//www.screener.in//company/517360/consoli...
4      5.  Sri Lak.Sar.Arni    32.70            10.89    0.00   -6.47        -781.05     35.87        -11.69   694.63            https//www.screener.in//company/521161/
..    ...               ...      ...    ...       ...     ...     ...            ...       ...           ...      ...                                                ...
220  221.  Glaxosmi. Pharma  1336.25  51.98  22618.88    2.25  164.56          13.33    802.30         -1.67    36.66  https//www.screener.in//company/GLAXO/consolid...
221  222.    Nitin Spinners   206.80   5.49   1162.35    1.93   31.58         -66.14    537.20        -23.79    36.63         https//www.screener.in//company/NITINSPIN/
222  223.  Timescan Logist.   120.30  14.49     42.03    0.00    0.41                    27.18                  36.52          https//www.screener.in//company/TIMESCAN/
223  224.            Mastek  1648.40  17.52   5015.34    1.15   67.12         -12.85    658.66         19.34    36.48  https//www.screener.in//company/MASTEK/consoli...
224  225.     Lloyds Metals   279.50  16.35  12432.84    0.18  230.03         813.91    999.62        494.06    36.41        https//www.screener.in//company/LLOYDMETAL/

[225 rows x 12 columns]
```

Comment: i face error please try and update Google Colab in this link.   https://colab.research.google.com/drive/15t5wIyVXNIiO-UjSTQ0VHp93_DAYBPPl?usp=sharing

Comment: @RKSolanki. I fixed it. I replace the `|=` operator (update operator -> Python 3.9) by `update` method.

Comment: Sir I only get as much data as in the first formula. Next to them i.e next to ROCE you need column number 12(Prom. Hold) and 13(Change in Prom Hold) from another URL link [https://www.screener.in/screens/881791/rk-holding/]. Lookup values match and look for the data next to them. Lookup value column number will be 2 (name). Please try in Your Python Script. [https://colab.research.google.com/drive/15t5wIyVXNIiO-UjSTQ0VHp93_DAYBPPl?usp=sharing]

Comment: Sir Please need Help. in this Python Script Making. Thank You So much Sir...

Comment: Sir Already Questioned Please Read this Thread.....and get Expected Result using Python Script.. [https://stackoverflow.com/a/75041662/20621143]

Comment: Just add 2 items to `cols`: `cols = ['S.No.', 'Name', 'CMP', 'P/E', 'Mar Cap', 'Div Yld', 'NP Qtr', 'Qtr Profit Var', 'Sales Qtr', 'Qtr Sales Var', 'ROCE', 'Prom. Hold', 'Change in Prom Hold']` and change url to `url = 'https://www.screener.in/screens/881791/rk-holding/?page={}'`

Comment: @RKSolanki. https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TwdY.png

Comment: Sir I see 13 columns. However, I requested 17 columns. You can see in the link :[https://colab.research.google.com/drive/15t5wIyVXNIiO-UjSTQ0VHp93_DAYBPPl?usp=sharing%5D]. Sir solve this last problem please sir

Comment: Sir Only 13 Column Fetch after add 3rd URL then 14 column not fetch.. please see code on Google Colab.... Please Sir.....This is the last problem i faced.. Sir i appreciate you

Comment: I think you need to have an account to download other columns.

Comment: I need your help special. Please sir

This link is open. No login account is needed. 2 link data is equal. And I do not want to get a 5 link data column. When I reduce the 2 -link column, I get 1 and 2 link data. But there are only 3 columns. Even if you use more than 3 links. Which is tried in this Google Colab link. [https://colab.research.google.com/drive/15t5wIyVXNIiO-UjSTQ0VHp93_DAYBPPl?usp=sharing%5D%5D]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot in the Colab notebook of what is wrong? I don't fully understand the problem.

Comment: Maybe you can open a new question with a large explanation?

Comment: Both are shown in practical detail in screenshots. Screenshot : 1 - [https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3vTD.png] Screenshot : 2 - [https://i.stack.imgur.com/13x2b.png] Even if you try to get more columns, it is not giving more than 13 columns. It will give me data in 13 columns only. Inside #cols which will give the data of the first 13 columns only. Please watch and try this Google Colab link: [https://colab.research.google.com/drive/15t5wIyVXNIiO-UjSTQ0VHp93_DAYBPPl?usp=sharing]  Sir Please Solved this problem. Thank you so much Sir.

Comment: Oh ok I got it. Just because you add more columns to the `cols` variable doesn't mean you'll get more data from the current URL. Each table has its own number of columns, no less, no more.

Comment: Sir this is possible or not...? Please try if possible.

Comment: No it's not possible, for `dii-holding` you have a fixed number of columns, for `fii-holding` another set and so on. You have a common set between each url and a variable set for the specific url. I can't create other data that do not exist. I'm sorry.

Comment: Sir you have answered my question very well and also you have helped me for some extra work in this script and also answered the comment well.  Thank you very much for that.  Your work is very nice.  You will make great progress.  I thank you from the bottom of my heart.

Answer (score 1):

As @Corralien mentioned since `pandas 1.5.0` there is [`extract_links`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) available. Depending on the extent of the readjustments, I would also choose the direct approach via `BeautifulSoup`, as this allows more flexibility.

##### Example

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://www.screener.in/screens/881782/rk-all-stocks/?page={}'

df = pd.concat([pd.read_html(url.format(i), header=None, extract_links='body')[0] for i in range(1,10)])   

# extract the href from name column tuple and prepend base_url
df['Link'] = 'https://www.screener.in'+df['Name'].str[1]

# convert all columns except last one (Link) from tuple to string 
for c in df.columns[:-1]:
    df[c] = df[c].str[0]

# filter all out all subheaders or footer rows
df[(df['S.No.']!='S.No.') & (df['S.No.'].notna())]

# or filter and reorganize columns to fit your needs
# df = df[(df['S.No.']!='S.No.') & (df['S.No.'].notna())][['S.No.', 'Link', 'Name', 'CMP  Rs.', 'P/E', 'Mar Cap  Rs.Cr.', 'Div Yld  %','NP Qtr  Rs.Cr.', 'Qtr Profit Var  %', 'Sales Qtr  Rs.Cr.','Qtr Sales Var  %', 'ROCE  %']]
```

##### Output

|  | S.No. | Link | Name | CMP Rs. | P/E | Mar Cap Rs.Cr. | Div Yld % | NP Qtr Rs.Cr. | Qtr Profit Var % | Sales Qtr Rs.Cr. | Qtr Sales Var % | ROCE % |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | https://www.screener.in/company/536456/ | R J Bio-Tech | 6 |  | 5.68 | 0 | -17.41 | 33.07 | 1.74 | 1833.33 | 2400 |
| 1 | 2 | https://www.screener.in/company/FORBESGOK/consolidated/ | Forbes & Co | 627.2 | 0.17 | 809.09 | 0 | -4.08 | -128.11 | 103.43 | -24.35 | 1216.69 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 24 | 224 | https://www.screener.in/company/MASTEK/consolidated/ | Mastek | 1648.4 | 17.52 | 5015.34 | 1.15 | 67.12 | -12.85 | 658.66 | 19.34 | 36.48 |
| 25 | 225 | https://www.screener.in/company/LLOYDMETAL/ | Lloyds Metals | 279.5 | 16.35 | 12432.8 | 0.18 | 230.03 | 813.91 | 999.62 | 494.06 | 36.41 |